# Escape dots in YAML keys in Helm unittest

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Would someone know how to escape dots . in Helm and precisely the unittest plugin?
The template

```
[...]
spec:
  config:
    my.config: "foo"
```

The test

```
[...]
asserts:      
  - equal:
    path: "spec.config.my\.config"
    value: "foo"
```

Throws

```
yaml: line 23: found unknown escape character
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [helm-unittest documentation](https://github.com/helm-unittest/helm-unittest/blob/main/DOCUMENT.md) states:

> Map keys in `path` containing periods (`.`) are supported with the use of a `jsonPath` syntax: For more detail on the [`jsonPath`](https://github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath#syntax) syntax.

The example syntax looks like `root.ancestor.parent["dotted.field.name"]`.  Adapting it to your example,

```yaml
asserts:      
  - equal:
    path: spec.config["my.config"]
    value: "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Indeed one should read the doc thoroughly it's quite explicitely mentioned